# display a block element below a floating element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a menu  with `float:right` which should be displayed above the content of my site.
At the moment the content is displayed behind the menu because of the floating property. Can you solve that?

The code: http://jsbin.com/tomaj/2/edit

the actual situation:
[image]

how it should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your block div the following CSS

```
clear: both;
```